# Sorting table on column click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am having issues sorting columns. I have a table that is populated with data and it is organized with `DESC`. I would like to make it so that, when one of the columns is clicked, it will change back and forth between `ASC` and `DESC`.

While I was clicking on a specific column, these parameters were being sent:

```
Parameters: {"search"=>{"meta_sort"=>"date.asc"}}
```

as well as just making the same query as when initially accessed.

Here is my controller code:

```
def dashboard
  @search = Quality.search(params[:search])
  @qualities = @search.page params[:page]

  @qualities_failed = Quality.where('last_disposition_state = ?','fail').order("strftime('%Y',date) DESC, julian_date DESC, lot DESC, time DESC").limit(10).search(params[:search])
  @qualities_passed = Quality.where('last_disposition_state = ?','pass').order("strftime('%Y',date) DESC, julian_date DESC, lot DESC, time DESC").limit(10).search(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
    format.xlsx {
      send_data Quality.order("strftime('%Y',date) DESC, julian_date DESC, lot DESC, time DESC").limit(10).to_xlsx.to_stream.read, :filename => 'passed.xlsx', :type => "application/vnd.openxmlformates-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    }
  end
end
```

I would like to know how I could take those parameters and, from what I can tell, make an `if` statement that would evaluate the parameter and sort the table based on that.

```
if -> == ASC then (query with ASC instead of DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the sorting to occur in Rails or in the browser?

Since the browser already has the data, there are good arguments to be made that the sort should occur in JavaScript within the page. The user's experience will be better/faster, and you won't be burdening Rails and the hosting hardware and database with another request.

There are many JavaScript plugins for jQuery and other JavaScript libraries that make it easy to do this.

Comment: That does seem like a better option and I have a fair bit of knowledge in regards to jquery and js.